# Service and/or tool to monitor performance?

Tags: performance, monitoring

I am seeing wildly different performance from a clients web site, and would like to set up some sort of monitoring.

What I'm looking for is a service that will issue requests to a couple of URLs, and report on the time it took to process the page - [TTFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) and time to download the entire page - that means I need something that will process javascript & css.

Are there services like this?  I've seen a few that monitor uptime, but they don't seem to report on the overall page performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), which is an HTTP performance tool.

It is not so user friendly, as you should learn how to code test cases, but it is complete and consistent enough, and also has some good performance graphs in output.

Comment: I'm looking for a service that runs outside of my local network, because it's part of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are seeking, but here is my idea: First, JMeter can test outside your network, you just need to inform correct URLs to fetch. Then you create your test cases (what to fetch, what to check, what and how to report). Finally set up a scheduled event on your - or another with JMeter - machine to run in the intervals you want, like cronjob. After that, just check logs/outputs.

Comment: I ended up running tests using jMeter from both inside and outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

why not try http://host-tracker.com/ :)